# Can I change the z-index stacking order for position: absolute elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

Here's my code:

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.rel {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #efefef;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
.abs2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: -40px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.shift {
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rel">
    <div class="abs">
        <div class="abs2">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rel"></div>
<div class="rel">
    <div class="abs">
        <div class="abs2 shift">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rel"></div>
<div class="rel"></div>
```

Is it possible to stack the green "abs2" div above the second red "abs" div? There are both positioned absolute (every green "abs2" div should be above every red "abs" div).

I know there is something called a stacking context, but I can't figure out how to make my example work. It seems impossible if I read [Mozilla's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa87mme/17/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all elements having `.abs` share the same stacking context, you could give a higher `z-index` value to that one containing the green block.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa87mme/12/)**

```
<div class="rel">
    <div class="abs higher"> <!--
                    ^-- Added class -->
        <div class="abs2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rel"></div>
<div class="rel">
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.abs { position: absolute; z-index:1; }

.abs.higher {
    z-index: 2; /* anything bigger than 1 */
}

.abs2 { position: absolute; z-index:1; }
```

---

### Update

As per your update:

> Is it possible to stack the green `.abs2` div above the second red
>   `.abs` div? [...] **every** green `.abs2` div should be **above
>   every** red `.abs` div.

Currently both `.abs` and `.abs2` establish new stacking contexts. Assuming the current markup in which `.abs2` is nested within `.abs`, there are two options:

**1)** The simplest, if it's possible, place `.abs2` *next* to (rather than inside) `.abs` in the markup, so that they could share the same stacking context: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa87mme/18/)**.

```
<div class="rel">
    <div class="abs"></div>
    <div class="abs2">1</div>
</div>
```

```css
.abs { position: absolute; z-index: 1; }
.abs2 { position: absolute; z-index: 2; }
```

**2)** Remove `z-index` property from `.abs` to let nested `.abs2` position on the top of all elements having `.abs` class: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa87mme/21/)**.

However as can be seen, in this approach some parts of `.abs` elements would go behind the following `.rel` containers. This is because positioned elements which sit in the same stacking context would stack with the respect to DOM hierarchy unless they have explicit `z-index` values.

Only in this particular instance <sup>1</sup> - based on the provided demo - we can sort of fix this issue by removing `relative` positioning of `.rel` elements. So from now on, `.abs` elements would be positioned with the respect to the initial containing block (visually, the viewport). This means `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` properties would be calculated relative to the viewport: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa87mme/23/)**.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is not a general solution. You should use this method with care.</sub>

Comment: sorry, this was not exactly what I was looking for, my bad! I oversimplified the example. I've updates the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give a higher z-index to the parent container as well. You already have `position: relative` on `rel` which is also necessary, so adding the z-index should do it.